# How to compile Ruby?

Tags: ruby, compilation

Is there a tool that can allow me to compile Ruby code so that it runs somewhat faster?

For example, I have heard that there is a tool for Python called "pyc" that allows us to compile the code, so that it runs 10 times faster.

Comment: The only use of the term "pyc" I am aware of is as the file extension for bytecode. There's Cython which is a different language that can be used to write fairly low-level code that gladly talks to Python (it accepts vanilla Python, but at best gives you one or two percent performance if you don't add type annotations). There's also PyPy which can achive tremedous speedups but you propably wouldn't consider it a compiler, as it's a JIT compiler. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542982/convert-ruby-to-low-level-languages for why this is a flawed idea.

Comment: pyc is just bytecode python, its not "10 times faster", it runs at precisely the same speed, however there might be a slightly faster bootup time as it doesnt need to convert the python code to bytecode at the start.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't, at least with MRI 1.8 (the standard). This is because 1.8 works by walking the Abstract Syntax Tree.  Python, Ruby 1.9, JRuby, and Rubinius use byte code, which allows compilation to an Intermediate Representation (byte code).  From MRI Ruby 2.3 it has become easy to do this, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44613584/1299362%20answer) below.

With Rubinius, you can do something as described in this post: http://rubini.us/2011/03/17/running-ruby-with-no-ruby/

In JRuby you can use the "Ahead Of Time" compiler through, I believe, jrubyc.

This isn't really the standard way of doing things and you're generally better off just letting your Ruby implementation handle it like it wants to.  Rubinius, at least, will cache byte code after the first compilation, updating it as it needs to.

Answer (score 11):

From `ruby 2.3.0` its so easy to compile your source code to bytecodes that the Ruby-VM understands.

```
byte_code = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_file '/home/john/somefile.rb'

File.binwrite '/home/john/bytecode', byte_code.to_binary
```

and in Command Line

```
$ cat bytecode 

YARB�
IUsx86_64-linux*.*1

+1�!AA*1
!qy��������yyQ� E/home/john/somefile.rbE<main>E <class:A>EshivaEhelloEAEputsEcore#define_methodu����� 5M
```

The content of the file

```
class A
  def shiva
    puts 'hello'
  end
end
```

### What is the purpose?

Well, ruby takes time to compile your source code into byte codes so you can load your bytecodes directly into ruby and execute. No overhead of grammar checking and compilation. It much faster than normal processes.

### How to load byte code?

```
bytecode = File.binread('/home/john/bytecode')
instruction_from_byte_code = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.load_from_binary bytecode

instruction_from_byte_code.eval
# => :shiva
```

> **Note**: This answer is tested in **MRI** only. It might or might not work in other Ruby Implementations

Comment: This is great thank you.  I had to use ```File.binread``` rather than ```File.readbin```, is that a typo?

Comment: Perhaps, it was Ruby 2.4.1

Answer (score 7):

In the beginning of 2013 there is not a way to translate Ruby into C/C++ source and then compile it.

However, I heard Matz (Yukihiro Matsumoto) say that  a researcher is creating this tool in Japan. The project should be founded by the Japanese government.

Otherwise you could use JRuby and compile it in Java byte-code or you could use Rubinius. Rubinius compiles automatically in byte-code (JIT compiler) for the Rubinius VM. It is possible to convert Rubinius in byte-code into LLVM IR and LLVM can generate machine code.

Comment: No I think someone is developing something like Hip Hop for PHP

Comment: "However, I heard Matz (Yukihiro Matsumoto) say that a researcher is creating this tool in Japan. The project should be founded by the Japanese government."

Any links to this? I would love to read more about this.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but I found a very interesting project that may provide an answer to your question: http://crystal-lang.org/

It basically compiles Ruby to native machine code. That's not exactly true because Crystal is not exactly Ruby and you might have to make some modifications to your code. There are also libraries that are not supported (yet) but to me it all looks very promising.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [Unholy](https://github.com/whymirror/unholy) git repo

Comment: I wouldn't recommend unholy. It seems like mostly a proof-of-concept, it takes a dependency on the python vm, and _why is not coming back.

Comment: vaporware?  hasn't been touched in 14 years

Answer (score 0):

The following "selfcontained" ruby test-case is based on the examples from this very thread, from the comment/answer of the user named illusionist.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#==========================================================================
# This file is in public domain.
# The code of this file is based on the code fragments at the
# 2018_12_09 version of the:
#
#     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902334/how-to-compile-ruby
#
# This file has been tested with the ruby version
#
#     ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
#
#-----start--of--the--boilerplate------------------------------------------

s_fp_home=ENV["HOME"].to_s
s_fp_tmp=s_fp_home+"/tmp" # using /tmp can be a security risk
s_fp_demofolder=s_fp_tmp+"/ruby_bytecode_usage_demo_01"

def create_folder_if_needed(s_fp_in)
   if !Dir.exists? s_fp_in
      Dir.mkdir(s_fp_in)
      if !Dir.exists? s_fp_in
         raise(Exception.new("\n\n Folder creation failed.\n"+
         "GUID=='d6e409cb-e072-4441-9421-22630190c2e7'\n"))
      end # if
   end # if
end # create_folder_if_needed
create_folder_if_needed(s_fp_tmp)
create_folder_if_needed(s_fp_demofolder)

s_rand=""
7.times{s_rand<<("_"+rand(100).to_s)}

s_fp_bytecode=s_fp_demofolder+"/awesome_bytecode"+s_rand
s_fp_src=s_fp_demofolder+"/x"+s_rand+".rb"

if File.exists? s_fp_src
   raise(Exception.new("\n\n This file should not exist yet.\n"+
   " s_fp_src=="+s_fp_src+"\n"+
   "GUID=='43ab3d45-1324-47af-9441-22630190c2e7'\n"))
end # if
IO.write(s_fp_src,"puts('');puts('Greetings from bytecode!');puts('')")
if !File.exists? s_fp_src
   raise(Exception.new("\n\n The file \n"+s_fp_src+"\n is missing.\n"+
   "GUID=='4aeb5e54-efe0-4111-a851-22630190c2e7'\n"))
end # if


#-----start--of--the--core--of--the--demo----------------------------------

bytecode_out = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_file(s_fp_src)
IO.binwrite(s_fp_bytecode, bytecode_out.to_binary)

bytecode_in = IO.binread(s_fp_bytecode)
instruction_from_byte_code = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.load_from_binary(bytecode_in)
instruction_from_byte_code.eval

#==========================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ruby-packer](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer) which creates executables from Ruby and Ruby on Rails applications

Comment: Nice one we use it but it creates difficulties with loading the native library with ffi, also if any native library accessing gem files on the file system highly likely you are in trouble

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're running CRuby.

You could experiment with the `--jit` flag when running Ruby to see if you gain any speed. Otherwise, I don't think you can compile Ruby scripts into native code yet. Only to bytecode via the `RubyVM` module but I don't think you'll gain anything from doing it.

Crystal-lang or GraalVM could be your alternative (with some possible changes) for higher performance.