# Constants in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, constants

I have a string like below,

```
STRING_FIRST = "Abcd. Efgh. ijkl"
```

I need to declare the above string as constant in ruby. But it gives complie time error on first dot(.).

Can any one please help.

Updating the actual code alike.

```
class class_name << Test::Unit:TestCase
  include module1

  STRING_FIRST = "Abcd. Efgh. ijkl"

  def method1
    xxx
  end
end
```

Comment: Your actual code must look differently. This one is fine, doesn't give any errors.

Comment: without the context in which you want to use that string, nobody can really help you. please show more of your code so we have a better overview about your situation

Comment: class names must start with a capital letter, and you use '<' to indicate the superclass, not '<<'

Comment: the compile error comes at line 3.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: That's not true. Apart from MRI, which is more or less obsolete by now, *all* current Ruby implementations have at least one compiler, some even more. YARV compiles to YARV bytecode, Rubinius compiles to Rubinius bytecode which it then further compiles to native machine code, MagLev compiles to GemStone/S bytecode which it then further compiles to native machine code, MacRuby compiles to native machine code, JRuby first interprets, then compiles to JVM bytecode, IronRuby first interprets, then compiles to CIL bytecode.

Comment: @Jorg, Doesn't MRI (at least since 1.9) also compile to bytecode?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Thanks. That shows how new I am to Ruby. That's why I actually did a little research before posting my comment and came across [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902334/how-to-compile-ruby). Looks like it is outdated, thanks for bringing me up to speed!

Comment: @WayneConrad: MRI doesn't support Ruby 1.9 and never will. There are no intentions of it ever supporting any version newer than Ruby 1.8. MRI is obsolete. Matz isn't even working on it any more, he has shifted his focus to YARV (Koichi Sasada's implementation of Ruby 1.9/2.0) and more recently MRuby (Matz's own new implementation of ISO Ruby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.3 I get a different error, and as [Frederick Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064226/frederick-cheung) points out, rightly so:

```
 syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting '<' or ';' or '\n'
```

You're inheriting using the shift operator, which is incorrect.