# Where can I compile my ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I started programming on ruby at codecademy but where can I compile my codes on doing a website? 
When I was making some lessons on C I used codeblocks to run codes. I know any text editor can run a HTML code. So what about ruby?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902334/how-to-compile-ruby)

Comment: Although the questioner uses the word "compile," it seems likely that that is just a poor word choice due to not knowing yet that Ruby is normally interpreted.  For that reason, I do not think this question is a proper duplicate of the nominated exemplar.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at answering the question that I *think* you're asking, but I'm not 100% sure here.

Ruby is an interpreted language (what does that mean?  Not a whole lot nowadays.  If you'd like a more in depth discussion on the distinction or lack thereof between interpreting vs compiling, read Jorg's comments below).  To execute ruby code, you'll need to install ruby.  Fortunately for you, this is freely available on any major platform.  If you're on something unix-y (eg, linux or mac), I'd strongly recommend installing ruby via something like rvm or rbenv.  If you're on windows, you can either go the cygwin route and pretend it's a unix-y environment, or there are prebuilt installers out there.  Googling 'install ruby' should have some sites that can help you at or near the top of the search results.

Comment: There is noch such thing as an "interpreted language". Languages are a set of abstract mathematical rules and restrictions. Languages aren't interpreted or compiled. They just *are*. Interpretation and compilation are traits of, well, an interpreter or compiler, not a language. Every language can be compiled, and every language can be interpreted. Most languages have both compiled and interpreted implementations. Most modern language implementations in fact use both within the same implementation. Case in point: all currently maintained Ruby implementations have a compiler.

Comment: While what you've said is accurate, I've found the distinction to be a useful one for most situations.  Ruby, in its most common usage, is passed exactly as is to an interpreter, which then executes the code, in contrast to something like C, which in its most common usage is compiled first, and then the binary produced is executed.  While neither of these *has* to be the way you use those languages, they are the most frequent paradigms.  OP may some day need to understand the distinction you've pointed out, but I do not think today is that day.

Comment: Ruby, in its most common usage, is passed directly as is to a *compiler*, not an interpreter. The *output* of that compiler may or may not, then, in turn, be passed to an interpreter, but no Ruby implementation today interprets Ruby code. YARV compiles to bytecode, then interprets. Rubinius compiles to bytecode, then either interprets or compiles to native code. JRuby in JIT mode compiles to JRuby IR, then either interprets or compiles further to JVM bytecode. JRuby in AOT mode compiles straight to JVM bytecode, *exactly* like `javac` does. If Ruby is an interpreted language, Java is too.

Comment: I've found the distinction to be a completely useless one. Packaging an interpreter together with the program into a single executable is indistinguishable from compilation. A fast compiler that directly executes its output is indistinguishable from an interpreter. The Futamura Projections allow you to automatically transform an interpreter into a compiler. PyPy automatically generates a JIT compiler from an interpreter. V8 is and has always been a pure compiler, yet, it behaves indistinguishable from an interpreter. The Scala and GHC Haskell REPLs are based on compilers, everybody assumes …

Comment: … they are interpreters. An interpreter and a compiler do almost the same things: an interpreter reads the code into a buffer, lexes the buffer into a token stream, parses the token stream into a parse tree, performs semantic analysis and transforms it into an abstract syntax tree, performs type inference (if applicable), type checking, overload resolution, etc., performs optimizations, and then traverses the tree, and for every node it encounters, it executes a piece of code implementing the meaning of that code. The *only* thing a compiler does different is to replace the word "execute" …

Comment: … with "output". I'm all for simplifications, but not if they are wrong and misleading. Just look at the questions in the [tag:ruby] tag, and how many of them are caused by simplifications and analogies that are simply untrue. E.g. "I know how to do this with an instance method, but how do I do it with a static method?" The answer is simple: there are no static methods in Ruby, every method is an instance method, so you already know the answer, it's just that someone has told you that "methods defined with `def self.` are like static methods in Java", which couldn't be further from the truth.

Comment: The difference is less a technical one and more of a usage one.  You don't (Jruby aside) generally take ruby and do anything with the compiled state other than immediately execute it.  You however do exactly that with C.  You're going for executable binaries or some variety of linkable object file.  On that level I find the analogy useful.  YMMV (and it clearly does).

Comment: BTW, editing my answer to reflect your views somewhat.